# Perl + Apache + CGI

Tags: windows, perl, apache, cgi

How do I run perl script from local host?

I have installed Apache 2.2 and Active Perl 5.16.3.
I am able to run the perl scrip from command prompt. 
But since i am dealing with web application, i want it to be run from localhost.

However, I am getting the following error in the browser

Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please help me out!

Comment: There should be more details in the server's error log.

Comment: What does your script look like?

Answer (score 0):

You could run cgi script from web browser. CGI  means that it should send a HTML header before sending any output to the server (which is going to send it back to the browser).

http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html#NAME

http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/perl/cgi.html

Like this:

```
use CGI; # load CGI routines
$q = CGI->new; 
print $q->header; # create the HTTP header
print $q->start_html('hello world'); # start the HTML

### your script logic goes here

print $q->end_html; # end the HTML
```

Of course, CGI is outdated, for new development you should use some mmore recent framwork like: Dancer, Mojolicious, ...

Comment: This solved my problem. The test script worked, but mine did not despite having identical permissions. It turns out the error was because my perl script was missing a header in its output: adding `print "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\n\n";` solves that.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably related to the configuration of Apache. (It may be Apache that needs configuring for .cgi scripts) - If this is the case then you can find good info on this here:

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=44536 
http://www.cgi101.com/book/connect/winxp.html 
http://www.editrocket.com/articles/perl_apache_windows.html

There is usually a host of things that you need to do to get it working. Following a good HOWTO to make sure that everything is installed and configured correctly will usually get you going to execute scripts on your local Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

if someone is looking for an answer in year 2017 then follow this on windows 2010 machine.

1. Download Strawberry perl from perl site
   Install in default directory.C:\Strawberry
2. Download Apache from https://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi#apache24
3. Once you successfully get apache server running then
4. Place your perl scripts in your Apache24/cgi-bin/ folder.
   firstline of your perl script should point to path where perl is installed for my case it is #!C:/Strawberry/perl/bin/perl.exe 
   you should change your path according your installation folder

Filename - first.pl

```
#!C:/Strawberry/perl/bin/perl.exe
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "Hello, World.";
```

5. Now you can run your script from browser http://localhost/cgi-bin/first.pl